# ¿Por qué la barra de navegación me crea un vacío?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, nav

En una página web en el dispositivo móvil la barra de navegación se extiende hacia la derecha. Esto provoca que en la pantalla podamos hacer scroll aunque la parte derecha este sin contenido. En tal caso, se ve vacío, quedando un hueco, y llegando arriba, se ve la barra de navegación extendida a la derecha. Sin embargo, no debería poder hacerse scroll.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal para que la barra se extienda provocando ese vacío?

Dejo el código, a ver si es suficiente para ver mis errores.

La web en cuestión es [agrochema.es](http://agrochema.es) y vean el error que tiene, tanto en la página principal, como en la página de precios.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:400,600,700');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#logo {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -0.6em 0;
}

#contact {
  height: 150px;
}

html nav.navbar.navbar-custom {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #111;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #008000 !important;
}

h1.h-xlight,
h2.h-xlight,
h3.h-xlight,
h4.h-xlight,
h5.h-xlight,
h6.h-xlight {
  font-weight: 200;
}

h1.h-light,
h2.h-light,
h3.h-light,
h4.h-light,
h5.h-light,
h6.h-light {
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.h-bold,
h2.h-bold,
h3.h-bold,
h4.h-bold,
h5.h-bold,
h6.h-bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1.font-light,
h2.font-light,
h3.font-light,
h4.font-light,
h5.font-light,
h6.font-light {
  color: #fff;
}

.big-heading {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.text-center {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.service-desc p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p.lead {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.highlight-light {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #111;
}

a {
  color: #666;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.light {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-logo {
  display: flex;
}

#navigation {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* codigo de Alvaro Montoro  */

div#navigation-sticky-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 121;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 21px;
  border-top: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
  outline: 0;
}

.divider-header {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider-short {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.navbar .navbar-custom {
  padding: 0;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  }
  @media (max-width:768px) {
    #navigation {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    .site-logo {
      margin: 0 0 0 30px;
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
      color: #eee;
    }
    .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
    .navbar-header {
      margin-top: -40px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar-header button {
      background: #111;
    }
    .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
      padding: 4px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-custom .nav {
      background: #444;
    }
    .service-box {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .team-wrap {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .xs-marginbot-20 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
  .marginbot-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .marginbot-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-40 {
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-60 {
    margin-bottom: 60px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-70 {
    margin-bottom: 70px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-80 {
    margin-bottom: 80px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-90 {
    margin-bottom: 90px !important;
  }
  .marginbot-100 {
    margin-bottom: 100px !important;
  }
  .margintop-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .margintop-10 {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .margintop-20 {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .margintop-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .margintop-40 {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .margintop-45 {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .margintop-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
  #container-2 {
    background-color: #EBB250;
  }
  .home-section {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 120;
  }
  .home-section2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 120;
  }
  .inner-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
  }
  .home-section.nopadd-bot {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .section-heading h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .section-heading p {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  .color-dark .section-heading h2 {
    color: #111;
  }
  .color-dark .section-heading p {
    color: #444;
  }
  .color-dark .divider-short {
    background: #666;
  }
  .color-dark .divider-header {
    background: #666;
  }
  .color-light .divider-short {
    background: #666;
  }
  .color-light .divider-header {
    background: #666;
  }
  .color-light .section-heading h2 {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .color-light .section-heading p {
    color: #fefefe;
  }
  .color-light blockquote,
  .color-light p {
    color: #fefefe;
  }
  .bg-white {
    background: #fff;
  }
  .bg-gray {
    background: #f9f9f9;
  }
  .bg-dark {
    background: #404040;
  }
  .text-light {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .hero {
    background: url(http://i41.tinypic.com/350t8nr.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 200px 0 200px 0;
    height: auto;
  }
  .hero h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    margin: 40px 0 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .hero h1 span {
    color: #a1a9b0;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .hero p {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fefefe;
  }
  .learn-more-btn {
    background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 1);
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
    margin: 60px 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .learn-more-btn:hover,
  .learn-more-btn:focus {
    background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
  }
  .intro {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .intro-inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 120px 0 20px;
  }
  .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .header-text h2 span {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .header-text h3 span {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  .btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
  }
  .service-desc .divider-header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .item {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  #contact {
    background-color: #C9E4E4;
  }
  .btn-lg,
  .btn-group-lg>.btn {
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .widget-contact {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .boxcol-25 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar .widget h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .sidebar .widget {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .widget ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .widget.widget_categories ul li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    content: "\e684";
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .widget.widget_recent_post ul li figure {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  }
  .widget.widget_recent_post ul li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .widget.widget_recent_post ul li:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .widget.widget_recent_post ul li h6 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .widget.widget_recent_post ul li span {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .widget .tagcloud a {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .widget .tagcloud a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
  }
  .btn {
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .btn.btn-noradius {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  a.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  .btn-red {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c83539;
    border-color: #c83539;
  }
  .btn-red:hover,
  .btn-red:focus,
  .btn-red:active,
  .btn-red.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border-color: #666;
  }
  .btn-red:active {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .btn-skin:hover,
  .btn-skin:focus,
  .btn-skin:active,
  .btn-skin.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border-color: #666;
  }
  .btn-default:hover,
  .btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28c3ab;
  }
  .btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  .banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .progress {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .progress-bar {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  .intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .intro-text {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Agrochema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
  <section class="hero" id="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right navicon">
          <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#">
            <span></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center inner">
          <div class="animatedParent">
            <h1 class="animated fadeInDown">Servicio </h1>
            <p class="animated fadeInUp">Desbrozamos.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div id="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="site-logo">
              <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active">
                  <a href="#intro">Casa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#about">Sobre mi</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#service">Servicios</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="galerias.html">Trabajos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#service">Ser</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="galerias.html">Trabajos</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
    <div class="container marginbot-50">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
              <h2 class="h-bold">¿.?</h2>
              <div class="divider-header"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 animatedParent">
          <div class="text-center">
            <p>Realizamos</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin btn-scroll">Mas </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="service" class="home-section color-dark bg-gray">
    <div class="container marginbot-50">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div>
            <div class="section-heading text-center">
              <h2 class="h-bold">¿Què ?</h2>
              <div class="divider-header"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row animatedParent">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
              <div class="service-box">
                <img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/350t8nr.jpg">
                <div class="service-desc">
                  <p> Desbrozamos</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="animated rotateInDownRight slower">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-desc">
                <img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/350t8nr.jpg">
                <p>Venta</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
  </footer>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No se si no logré captar la pregunta, pero he probado el código en diferentes navegadores y no logro ver el error que comentas, ¡¿quiero entender que es scroll que comentas es horizontal ?

Comment: Y ya probaste agregando una medida para cada tipo de pantalla ej: `col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9`?

Comment: Si @SilvestreSilva, en el pc funciona de maravilla, pero en el dispositivo móvil, la barra de navegación, se extiende hacia la derecha horizontalmente, y deja hay un vacío, Mira la web por ti mismo [agrochema.es se llama](http://agrochema.es) verás el efecto que hace, tanto en el apartado en pantalla principal, como en la del formulario. En formulario, extiende el texto, en vez de que valla bajando, y en principal crea un hueco horizontal en la parte derecha, y subes hacia arriba y se ve el nav-bar extendido horizontalmente. Respecto a lo que dice Checho Parrado, no se como hacerlo,

Comment: Acabo de probar en el móvil, en mozilla y la página principal se ve bien, pero la de precios, no se ve completa y esta orrible.

Comment: @Miguel te recomiendo leer cómo generar un [MCVE], sobre todo la parte de **mínimo**

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano voy a editarlo para quitar lo posible, perdón, es  tanto el ansia que tengo en resolver el problema que me olvido de muchos detalles.

Comment: A mi forma de ver, el problema está cuando declaras los media queries. Pásate por [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) y echa un vistazo.

Comment: Gracias @tcm pero no veo la solución, volveré a verlo otra vez pero encuentro como arreglar el problema.

Comment: He vuelto a revisar es interesante articulo, pero soy incapaz de elegir la forma, quizá cuando le lea 500 veces, lo entenderé. He pillado la idea, pero no se plasmarla.

Comment: El dispositivo móvil en el que tiene el fallo es iPhone o Android?

Comment: Es android y con Chrome. En Mozilla la pagina principal va perfecta, pero en la de precios no aparece todo el contenido. @MarcosGiner

Comment: El problema no está en la barra de navegación, a pesar de lo que parece. Es sólo que cuando la pones en "fixed" se desliga del tamaño de su contenedor y toma el 100% de lo disponible. No puedo asegurarlo sin clonar tu web, pero tengo la fuerte sensación de que quién da problemas es las animaciones en la sección `#service`. Intenta eliminar la sección y ver si persiste. Si es eso, ya sabemos dónde actuar.

Comment: Gracias @delCano, quite esa sección y sigue haciéndolo mismo, aparte que en la página de precios, no esta esta seccion y tambien se extiende el contenido a lo ancho. Ya no se que cambiar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema parece estar con las animaciones que tienes (aunque no he conseguido identificar cuál de ellas en particular pero podría ser por los estilos del `fadeIn`). Inicialmente los elementos quedan fuera de la pantalla y los animas para que aparezcan en pantalla, pero se hace usando transformaciones y parece que a algunos navegadores no termina de gustarles.

Sé que es una solución algo "bruta", pero el problema desaparece haciendo que todo lo que esté fuera del ancho esté oculto. Para eso sólo tienes que añadir:

```
.container { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

> Para más información sobre esta respuesta, revisar [conversación del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74383/problema-con-la-navegacion)

Comment: Gracias @Alvaro Montoro, he solucionado el problema a medias, la página principal funciona, pero la de precios si aplico `overflow-x: hidden;` Publique [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145758/como-soluciono-el-error-creado-por-overflow-x-hidden/145766?noredirect=1#comment273890_145766) en la que me an intentado ayudar, pero no termino de solucionar. Si tienes alguna idea, si no pues tendré que poner recompensa. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que te voy a proponer no es realmente una solución; puesto que no hemos encontrado exáctamente la causa. Sin embargo, he hecho unos tests y sí que parece funcionar sin problemas.

Yo he metido ésta linea en el bloque de CSS de `html` directamente; pero quizá sea más prudente supeditarlo a una media query apropiada.

```
html {
    /* ... tu contenido ... */
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @delCano , efectivamente era con `overfow-x: hidden;` , pero no en el html, sino en `.container`me lo propuso Alvaro Montoro en el chat. Al ponerlo en `html`eliminaba las animaciones. En cuanto corrija su respuesta, debo aceptar su respuesta. Si bien estaría bueno saber como haces esos text, y en ocasiones venideras, poder hacerlo por mi cuenta sin tener que recurrir tanto a stackoverflow. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es gran cosa. Lo primero y fundamental, forzar un marco a todo: `* { border: 1px solid red!important; }`. Con eso podemos encontrar qué componentes dan problemas. Segundo, mucho inspector de CSS para activar y desactivar lineas. Y tercero, comentar bloques del HTML para localizar quién está causando los errores.

Comment: Gracias @del Cano , me a comentado Alvaro Montoro que se debe a los` (.grid_8 y grid_4)` que no deben ser compatibles. Tengo otra pregunta abierta con la sección de precios que es la que me da los problemas. Voy a intentar cambiar los `grid_8 , grid_4`por columnas a ver si lo corrijo, es lo único que queda, bueno tiene mas errores, como el botón de enlace en el móvil, los enlaces que apenas se ven... pero eso ya intentare solucionar. No obstante, me parece buena tu idea

Comment: Bootstrap es muy útil para hacer un prototipo rápido, pero a la larga es muy mala herramienta. Crea malos hábitos en el diseñador y hace muchas cosas que pueden interferir con lo que quieres hacer. Es difícil eliminarlo de un proyecto ya existente, pero te aconsejo dejar de usarlo para el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo este meta en el head del html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Comment: Gracias @Marc Puigventós Sanz , no funciona.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso nunca funcionaría de la manera en la que lo pusiste en la página web. Porque estás poniendo éste y después el tuyo. De todos modos, esto parece que no termina de resolver el problema.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74383/problema-con-la-navegacion