# ¿ Como soluciono el error creado por overflow-x: hidden;?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, interfaz-gráfica, nav

Buenas ayer @Alvaro Montoro me resolvio el problema que tenia con mi web en dispositivos móviles, [como verán en preguntas destacadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144822/por-qu%C3%A9-la-barra-de-navegaci%C3%B3n-me-crea-un-vac%C3%ADo). Bien, estaba tan contento, pero hoy he visto que al añadir `overflow-x: hidden;`, solucione el tema de móvil, pero se estropeo en el pc. Esta página debería ser [como en esta imagen](http://prntscr.com/iqisg3), ordenado en columnas, pero al añadir `overflow-x: hidden;`para que funcione en el móvil, también lo estira en el pc. 
¿ Habría forma de solucionar este problema, y que funcionara en los dispositivos bien ?
Por otro lado, se me añadieron barras de scroll  verticales en alguna zonas, como la barra de navegación. Eso lo dejaré para otra pregunta.
Gracias.Espero se vea con el código que añado, intentó reducir al máximo, siempre tienen regañarme.

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Denk+One);

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic);
/* Otra colavoracion mas de Alvaro Montoro*/
.container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
}


html {

    width: 100%;

}

a[href^="tel:"] {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#navigation{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #908e8e;
    font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#container .column {

    padding-top: 0px !important ;
  }


#works{
 background-color: #A4EB8F;
 padding-top: 10px ;
 padding-bottom: 30px ;
 
}
#works p{
 font-size: 20px ;
}

#informacion h2{
    padding-top: 10px ;
}




.ic {
 border:0;
 float:right;
 background:#fff;
 color:#f00;
 width:50%;
 line-height:10px;
 font-size:10px;
 margin:-220% 0 0 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0
}

strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}

address {
    font-style: normal;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.p1 {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

input {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    outline: none !important;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #474343;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Denk One', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-top: 83px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2.head1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    padding-top: 99px;
}

h3  {
    padding-top: 69px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font: 30px/43px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.page1 h3 {
    padding-top: 98px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 34px;
}

h4.head1 {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4.head2 {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}


ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.list .count {
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 30px/48px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 49px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background-color: #25952a/*#3da9b6*/;
}

.list li {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list li+li {
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.list1 {
    margin-top: -3px;
}

.list1 li {
    position: relative;
}

.list1 li+li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.list1 li a:after {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c7c6c6;
    height: 1px;
}

.list1 li a:hover:after {
    background-color: #25952a;/*#3da9b6;*/
    width: 0;
}

.list2  {
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.list2 li {
    background: url(../img/dots.png) 0 72% repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list2 li+li {
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.list2 .prod {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.list2 .price {
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.list2  {
    overflow: hidden;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.btn  {
    margin-top: 73px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 22px 62px 24px;
    background-color: #25952a /*#3da9b6*/;
    font: bold 30px/40px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.link1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font: 24px/26px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: #3b3a3a;
}

.paeg1 .link1 {
    margin-top: 14px;
}


.mb__0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.m0 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.pad0 {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.img_inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}



.fleft {
    float: left;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.page1 .fleft {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.rel {
    position: relative;
}


.oh {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fright {
    float: right !important;
}
.upp {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.alright {
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper, .extra_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear {
    float: none !important;
    clear: both;
}

.oh {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.page1 header h1{
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.content {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.page1 .content {
    padding-bottom: 36px;
}

.text1 {
    color: #6a6a6a;
    margin-top: -21px;
    font: 20px/22px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.ban_img {
    margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.link22{
    color: #844007;
}

.links a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.links li+li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/*Blocks*/

.box {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: #79c4ca;
    font: 36px/43px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.box_bot  {
    padding-top: 63px;
    padding-bottom: 69px;
}

.box_bot span {
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.block1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block1+.block1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

/**Seps**/
.sep__1 {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.sep__2 {
    padding-top: 77px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.sep__3 {
    height: 92px;
}
.color1 {
    color: #25952a/*#3da9b6*/;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.color1 a:hover, a.color1:hover {
    color: #474343;
}

.color2 {
    color: #474343;
}

.td_und {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.top {
    margin-bottom: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 82px;
    height: 82px;
    transition: 0s ease;
    -o-transition: 0s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0s ease;
}

.top:hover {
    background-position: right 0;
}



.copy {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.sub_copy {
    margin-top: -4px;
}


body {
    min-width: 1200px;
  }
  
  /* Containers*/
  .container_12 {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1200px;
  }

  .grid_4 li{
      font-size: 16px;
  }

  .grid_4 p{
    font-size: 16px;
}

  
  .push_1, .pull_1,
  .push_2, .pull_2,
  .push_3, .pull_3,
  .push_4, .pull_4,
  .push_5, .pull_5,
  .push_6, .pull_6,
  .push_7, .pull_7,
  .push_8, .pull_8,
  .push_9, .pull_9,
  .push_10, .pull_10,
  .push_11, .pull_11,
  .push_12, .pull_12 {
      position:relative;
  }
  
  .alpha {
      margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  .omega {
      margin-right: 0;
  }
   
  .container_12 .grid_4 {
      width:370px;
  }
  
  .container_12 .grid_8 {
      width:770px;
  }

  .clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0 30px ;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--Esta pagina esta funcionando gracias a la colaboracion de ALVARO Montoro en varias partes de la misma. En ella tambien me ayudo Edgar Gutièrrez -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai|Cormorant+Upright|Farsan" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
 <div class="loader">
 </div>
 <div id="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="site-logo">
       <img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active">
         <a href="../index.html">Casa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="../galerias.html#about">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="../galerias.html">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="../galerias.html">Trabajos</a>
        </li>

        <li>
         <a href="#works">Contacto</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
       <h2 class="h-bold">Nuestros precios...</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="container">-->
  <section class="content">
   <div class="ic"></div>
   <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_8">
     <h4 class="head1">Revise nuestros precios</h4>
     <div class="grid_4 alpha">
      <p class="color1">Ponemos a su servicio nuestra larga experiencia y los materiales de primeras marcas. La mayor calidad, al menor precio...</p>
      <ul class="list2">
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Mantenimiento mensual</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">Desde 50€</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Mantenimiento de comunidades</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de cesped *</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cesped artificial</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidado de setos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidado de rosales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantas ornamentales </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Diseño de jardines</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">Variable...</div>
       </li>

       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>(*)En la plantación de césped natural, le ofrecemos un mes de mantenimiento gratuito, y asegurar su agarre y proliferación.</a>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="price">$80,22</div>-->
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="grid_4 omega">
      <p class="color1">Limpieza y desbroce de fincas. Trabajos de campo, especialistas en huerta ecologica.</p>
      <ul class="list2">
       <br>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Sembramos su huerta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidamos su huerta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Arado de fincas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Rotulamos las fincas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de viñedos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Siembras ecologicas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de frutales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>



    <div class="grid_4">

     <p class="color1">
      <a href="#">Venta de leña, amplia variedad...</a>
     </p>
     <br>
     <p class="p1">En Agrochema ponemos a su disposición venta de leña a todo el Valle del Tietar: cerezo desde 70€ / 750 kg aprox.; fresnodesde 100€ 850kg aprox. Contamos con màs variedad
      <a href="#" class="link22">Aquì tiene una muestra.</a>
     </p>
     <p class="color1">
      <a href="#">Servicio de portes </a>
     </p>
     <p class="p1">En Agrochema ponemos a su disposición servicio de porte con remolque para todo el Valle del Tietar: portes de aceitunaa la almazara; portes de toda clase escombs</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="sep__2"></div>
   <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Trabajos en madera</h3>
     <ul class="list2">
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Vallados en madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>

      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Porches de madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Pèrgolas de madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Cabañas para herramienta</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Casetas de animales</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>(*)Toda la madera que utilizamos es de primera calidad, tratada para aguantar el paso de los años y las </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Nuestro compromiso</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a>Fiabilidad, innovación y determinación son los valores sobre los que se fundamenta nuestra empresa, el trabajo diario,las relaciones con los clientes y en la forma de hacer nuestro trabajo. Los equipos de trabajo nos unen, garantizandosí que conocimientos y experiencias se compartan y se apliquen en</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Nuestros objetivos</h3>
     <p>Nuestro objetivo es ofrecer cada día el mejor servicio posible,Ante todo, nos gusta trabajar cuidando el medio ambiente y tanto en limpieza como en jardinería somos</p>
     <br>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </section>
  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Parece que estás creando tu propio sistema de grid (`.grid_8` y `grid_4`) que no es adaptable. ¿Por qué no usar `col-XXX-YY` como ya haces en otras partes?

Comment: Utilice eso porque venía echo, pues no sabía cómo distribuir los precios de la manera que están. Venía con los puntitos entre texto y los precios,  que realmente es [una imagen](http://i64.tinypic.com/2ufrpyq.png). Que sistema de `col` debo utilizar, como en el formulario. Si no formulo una nueva pregunta para esto. Gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar lo de las barras de scroll, prueba utilizando `overflow: hidden` en lugar de solo en el eje X.

Por otro lado para solucionar tu problema lo más sencillo y rápido posible te recomiendo usar un media

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  .container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

De este modo solo afectará el overflow a los dispositivos INFERIORES en este caso a 425 píxeles de ancho de pantalla, que suele ser el tamaño de los móviles con más pantalla.

Comment: Gracias @David , pero no funciona, lo puedes ver tu mismo en el enlace a la pagina que hay en la pregunta.  Añadi lo siguiente `@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  .container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .container_12{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}`  Y quite lo `.container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
}` No se si es que no lo hago bien,. La verdad es que el scroll se quito.

Comment: el contenido del media reemplaza al contenido original cuando se cumpla la condicion del parentesis, por ejemplo si tienes un div con `color: black` y dentro del media lo tienes para menos de 425 pixeles como `color: green` cuando tu ventana tenga mas de 425 pixeles se vera el texto del div de color negro mientras que al redimensionar por debajo de los 425 pixeles el color seria verde, no se si me explico... eso se podría aplicar en tu caso con los overflow pero sería ir probando

Comment: tambien puedes probar con `@media all ...` en lugar del screen, o a poner una medida de pixeles más alta que se adapte a lo que necesitas

Comment: Buenas. A ver, si que funciono lo tu primera idea, pero he tenido problemas de conexión y resulta que volví a cargarla en el servidor y va bien. Si bien es cierto que tendré que estudiar lo que me dices del 
 "media", pues si que tengo problemas en el celular en la sección de precios con los colores del texto de los enlaces. y con el botón. @David Si tuvieras de algun sitio donde documentarme sobre ello para arreglar este problema, cuando hice el curso, esto no venía o no estuve en clase.Gracias.

Comment: Funciona en pc, pero en el móvil sigue todo descolocado @David Ya marque tu respuesta, no la voy a quitar, a ver si o soluciono para añadir a tu respuesta.

Comment: claro, aquí tienes un tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp